# How can I determine the git address of the machine I'm on?

Tags: git

I want to clone a bare repo I have setup but I could not remember the git address for running clone.

So I ssh'd into the machine.

```
ssh username@domain.com
```

Once I'm in the machine and I'm in the bare repo how can I determine it's address.

Once I have this I'm going to go back to my local machine and run:

`git clone i_need_this_url`

As a side, while I'm on the remote machine I can do

```
git remote -v
```

to see remote information but I want to see information for the machine I'm on.

Comment: You cannot find the url on https://github.com/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use git with ssh?

```
git clone ssh://user@server/path/to/project.git
```

or

```
git clone user@server:/path/to/project.git
```

where server is the machine you SSHed into and path/to/project.git is the path on the host machine.

[Docs here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-SSH-Protocol)

Comment: When you log in, type `pwd` (assuming it's a linux box) to see the full path or `readlink -f project.git`

Comment: If this is an online host, when you log in you won't be in the root directory so the path won't start with the `/`